# is it possible to have a module run in a different module?

Tags: python

is it possible to have something like

```
def Number():
  N = random.randint(1,20)
  return N
```

and then have this run in something like 'def numReroll()'

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: I don't understand the question. `def numReroll(): return Number()`

Comment: The title mentions modules, but there are no modules in the question, just two function definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean `function` not `module`, then one function can call another function -

```
import random

def Number():
  N = random.randint(1,20)
  return N

def numReroll()
    number1 = Number()
    number2 = Number()
    number3 = Number()
```